# CSV export then change headers and resave

Tags: excel, csv

I've looked around and hopefully somebody here can help me.

I'm currently using a CRM that allows me to export data to a CSV, but the fieldnames (column headers) can't be changed within the CRM, which is a problem as the program I want to import the CSV file into has different named headers.

I want to somehow export the CSV and automatically run a program to change the header names to match the template for our other program.

Is this possible? and is there any software I can use to do this?

Comment: XSLT is your friend. I guess. But to have it used automatically, I suppose you'd have to create a program that would use your CRM, then use the XLST. That being said, stackoverflow is about programming questions, merely asking for a software seems out of its policy.

Comment: Since you have tagged this with Excel: you can create an Excel file with the header you would like to have and an import specification which grabs the csv data starting with row 2

Comment: Roland, it's looking your suggestion is exactly what I need. Do you know of anything that will do this for me automatically (any software)? Or will I need to create a macro?  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have `head` and `sed` available you can replace the header line in file1.csv with that from file2.csv in a CSV like this:

```
( head -n 1 file2.csv; sed 1d file1.csv ) > newfile.csv
```